# Metro/JS Template for VS11 in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

So I seen a nice example layout in the http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#ShowMeTheTemplate Metro/JS Template for VS11.

It looks like this:

[image]

I really like the look of this and I was wondering how I could achieve this in WPF, not really that great with the various controls/layouts and content of WPF yet. Could anyone get me started with how to achieve something similar to this?

What I am really looking for is an xaml code snippet for VS2010 (WPF) of one of the group containers and how they are aligned as such in the picture? I mean I dont even really know what containers/controls you would use for something like this but it sure as hell looks sweet!

Bare in mind Im not fussed about the background/application title just something where I can get that type of grouping/structure and layout similar to this in vs2010 WPF?

Comment: Metro Ui tag, thanks @Bolt missed that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the default application in Visual Studio 11?

File -> New Project -> Visual C# or Javascript -> Grid application

UPDATE:

if you want to get more ideas about C#/XAML metro application before you install `Windows 8 Consumer Preview`, go to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx#adding_pages_and_navigation) page and take a look at the snippet.

Comment: Hey Louis no Im not on VS2011 yet I dont have the beta I just wanted to know if I could get something similar in my WPF VS2010? A pure xaml example no js needed I just like the look of it.

Comment: @Garrith If you are looking for building a metro style app, then you can only use VS11 on Win8. You can install VS11 on Win7, but I don't think you can build Metro Apps on Win7. Are you looking for the source code for the default application in C#/XMAL?

Comment: Yes, I just like the above style of that application and because im not so good with wpf I was hoping someone could give an example of how you could achieve that look in xaml.

Comment: @Garrith. Snippet on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx#adding_pages_and_navigation maybe helpful for getting a basic understanding

Comment: Wow nice find! That should hopefully help :D put that in your answer Louis!